How to make fields readonly in Chat SnapIn of Salesforce?
I am using the below code for is there anyway to make FirstName and LastName readonly
const initESW = function(gslbBaseURL) {
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
embedded_svc.settings.prepopulatedPrechatFields = {
FirstName: contact.firstName || "",
LastName: contact.lastName || "",
Email: contact.email
};
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
embedded_svc.settings.displayHelpButton = true; //Or false
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
embedded_svc.settings.language = ''; //For example, enter 'en' or 'en-US'
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
embedded_svc.settings.enabledFeatures = [''];
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
embedded_svc.settings.entryFeature = '';
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
embedded_svc.init(
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  '',
  {
    baseLiveAgentContentURL: '',
    deploymentId: '',
    buttonId: '',
    baseLiveAgentURL: '',
    eswLiveAgentDevName: '',
    isOfflineSupportEnabled: false
  }
);

};
